# ArcGIS Desktop Extensions - turn on & off with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, extensions, shortcuts

I am familiar with assigning keyboard shortcuts for command in ArcGIS desktop. But, I'm trying to figure out if I can similarly assign keyboard shortcuts to turn specific extensions on & off, and if that is possible.
Using ArcMap, not Pro.

Comment: Shortcuts are for time saving. How much time it will save you?

Comment: A shorter, time-saving way to turn an extension on & off is a specific request from my team. If there is another idea, the help is appreciated.